# How can I modify my regular expression below to block the repetition of characters (not to be repeated more that two times in continuation)?

Tags: angularjs, regex

Below is the regular expression I want to modify to check the repetition of characters for not more than 2 times in **continuation**, see the below examples for more details. I have the regex for avoiding the repetition but I need both of them in the same expression. (**/(.)\1{2}/**)

For example:

```
Nameee : Invalid,
Naaame : Invalid,
Name   : Valid,
Naammee: Valid,
Nnname : Invalid.
```

I have

```
^(?!.*[AaEeIiOoUu]{5}).*[AaEeIiOoUu].*[a-zA-Z\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]*(?:-[a-zA-Z\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]*)?$
```

Comment: Add `(?!.*(.)(?:.*\1){2})` after the `^`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/ir0exq/1).

Comment: Or [`(?!.*(.)\1{2})`](https://regex101.com/r/ir0exq/2) if you mean they cannot appear in immediate succession.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżewit is blocking the repetition of characters 3 times anywhere in the whole string whereas it should block when it is in continuation.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/ir0exq/2/. You must use `i` modifier to make sure letters are treated in a case insensitive way.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, its working fine for me now. :)

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the chars cannot appear in immediate succession, you may add [`(?!.*(.)\1{2})`](https://regex101.com/r/ir0exq/2) to you pattern right after `^`. You must use `i` modifier to make sure letters are treated in a case insensitive way.

Updated regex will look like

```
/^(?!.*(.)\1{2})(?!.*[AEIOU]{5}).*[AEIOU].*[A-Z\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]*(?:-[A-Z\u00BF-\u1FFF\u2C00-\uD7FF]*)?$/i
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ir0exq/3)

The `(?!.*(.)\1{2})` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location (here, right after the string start) there are 0+ chars, followed with a tripled char: `(.)` captures a char into Group 1 and the `\1{2}` is the same value as in Group 1 (due to the `\1` backreference) that occurs 2 times (due to the `{2}` limited quantifier).